# Database design: I want to store the type of a house (apartment, villa, studio, etc..)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a database where I store houses. Each house can have multiple facilities, and each facility can have multiple values.

Let's say I want to store the type of a house (apartment, villa, studio, etc..).  What I'm thinking is to have a property_type table for the house types and a facilities table where I'll save the home_id and the property_type_id.

Is my thinking correct? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of what I picture.  I'm a bit confused about your definition of `facility` however.  I see facility as being like a gym, fitness center, or covered parking, etc.

```
 Property table
 | property_id | property_type_id
    111               001
    112               002


 Property type table
 | property_type_id | description
   001              |    house
   002              |   apartment
   003              |    villa


 Facility
 | facility_id      | description       |   property_id
 |    999           |  community bathroom |   111
 |    998           |  community kitchen |    111
 |    997           |  fitness center   |     112
 |    996           |  covered parking  |     111
 |    995           |  covered parking  |     112

 Tenant/Owner table
 | owner_id         |  property_id
 |   888            |   111
 |   887            |   112
```

Comment: Yes my mistake property type is not a facility, but actually my problem is how to store multiple values for each facility. Say a kitchen can have these values (Dish Washer,Fridge,Freezer,Hob,Oven,Microwave,Washing Machine,Blender,Coffee Maker,Toaster,Iron,Grill)

Comment: Make another table for components and link them back to the facility, just like how the facilities link back to the property.  You can keep creating tables to expand your one to many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly valid design, although probably more appropriate if a location can have more then one type.

In this situation I normally add a property_type_id directly on the location table, provided that all locations have a type (which seems likely in this case)

EDIT:
O wait, it seems like a single house can have multiple facilities. In that case I would create a facility table with a house_id on it, and add the property_type_id and any other pertinent information on the facility table.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is valid and there's nothing wrong about doing that. But why not use inheritance for your property types rather than using a property_type attribute? Inheritance between tables is done by using a PK-to-PK relationship. The implementation of this would prove its validity even more if different types of properties have common attributes (which would be place in the super-type/super-table) and different attributes which would go in the sub-types. Moreover, maybe one of these properties has a relationship with another table, but not all of the other properties actually have this relationship. But then again, that depends on your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If by "facility" you mean something akin to a feature of the property (which, by your comment on another answer, it seems you do), then what you have is called a many-to-many (or, shorter, M:M) relationship. That is, you have two "things":

- Properties
- Facilities

And each property may have multiple facilities, and any given facility can be present on multiple properties (in other words, a given property can have a pool or a microwave, and you can have multiple properties with a pool and multiple properties with a microwave).

In a relational database, M:M relationships are represented using an associative table. So, in general, your first two tables look like this:

```
Property
------------
Property ID
Description
etc.

Facility
------------
Facility ID
Description
etc.
```

Now, you need a table that, for each row, allows you to associate a given property to a given facility. That will look like this:

```
PropertyFacility
----------------
Property ID
Facility ID
```

This is basically a textbook M:M relationship, and should give you what you need.